# Taylor series of a function of $n$ variables

Tags: derivatives, calculus

How do we expand a function of $n$ variables, into a Taylor-series about a point $(a_1,a_2,.....,a_n)$. If this is the equilibrium point, I proceeded as follows :

$U(q_1,q_2,....,q_n) = U_0 + \sum_i^n {(q_i-a_i)\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}}|_{q=a_0} + \sum_i^n \sum_j^n{\frac{1}{2}(q_i-a_i)(q_j-a_j)\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial q_i \partial q_j}}|_{q=a_0} + ...... $

Since $a_0$ is equilibrium position, we can set the first order derivatives to be $0$. Is my working correct ? In several books, I've seen this to be written as :

$U(q_1,q_2,....,q_n) = U_0 + \sum_i^n {q_i\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}}|_{q=a_0} + \sum_i^n \sum_j^n\frac{1}{2}{q_iq_j\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial q_i \partial q_j}}|_{q=a_0} + ...... $

Instead of writing $(q_i-a_i)$ terms, they just wrote $q_i$. Did they set the equilibrium point to be reference point (origin) and set it to be $0$, or is there some deeper working that I'm failing to see.

In that case, $U_0$ can also set to be $0$, and the second order terms can be written in terms of a matrix, and higher order terms neglected.

We then have : $K_{ij} = {\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial q_i \partial q_j}}|_{q=a_0}$

Hence $U= \frac{1}{2} q^T K_{ij} q$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Yes. Thanks ....

Comment: Let me know if can help other

Comment: @AlBrown thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes first order derivatives are zero if a maximization has been solved (as long as solution was not at a boundary, which can happen for equilibria).
2. No those are not the same. Maybe a=0 is being assumed in the second case. If zero is the point where the derivatives are considered, a Taylor series is also called a Maclaurin series. People sometimes redefine U to be $U_{old} - U_0$ so as to make it a Maclaurin. Not the same. There is no “deeper working that youre failing to see”.
3. Why higher order terms neglected? Which ones? Do you mean they are not in the taylor expansion, or that they are small?